# getting "DateTime" of the last change in rows in a table in SQL Server?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, winforms, linq

Is there any way to find "DateTime" of the last change in rows in a table in SQL Server?

The changes (Insert / Update) are submitted by another windows application

And all I have in this table is insert_Date and there is no update_Date (and I can't add any columns or use triggers)

I've tried some queries, but all I got was the number of "User Updates" in a table, not the IDs of modified rows!

**I want to get rows which are modified or inserted after a specific DateTime**

Comment: Without having a column in a table recording that, I'm afraid that's impossible.

Comment: why can you not use triggers ?

Comment: @GuidoG because it's not my database and all i can do is to read data, I asked this question to check if there is a way to avoid syncing all unmodified data (which are almost 99% of it every time i read this database)

Comment: If the information is not in the table then no.

Answer (score 1):

If the information isn't stored in the table (or in another one by using a trigger for example) then it's impossible to track which rows were inserted after a determined datetime. You might find the time the last operation was executed at a table/index level (by querying `sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats`) but not at a record level.

You can't find data that doesn't exist!